# Telethon: I want to scrape all the links and just join the groups, not channels. but how to distinguish between them?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Here is my code and I need a way to get a True/False Boolean to find out whether if the received link is a group link or not.

```
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
#check whether there's a 'joinchat' in the msg text?
@client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=False, pattern=r'(?i).*joinchat/')) 
async def my_event_handler(event):
    #extract the hash of that link
    hash = re.search('(?<=joinchat\/)(\w+[-]?\S\w+)', event.raw_text).group(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out guys:

```
# checks whether there's a 'joinchat' in the msg text?
@client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing=False, pattern=r'(?i).*joinchat/'))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    # extracts the hash of that link
    hash = re.search('(?<=joinchat\/)(\w+[-]?\S\w+)', event.raw_text).group(0)
    checked = await client(CheckChatInviteRequest(hash=hash))
    if checked.megagroup and checked.broadcast == False:
        updates = await client(ImportChatInviteRequest(hash))

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Just note that if a group is a `megagroup`, that means it's a `Channel` (which can be either `megagroup` or `broadcast`). But indeed `ImportChatInviteRequest` is the right way to join a group by its private link.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as a solution for your question if it answers it, too.